# regarding maximum power transfer theorem and how is it difference from maximum efficiency attained

Tags: resistors

**What is the difference between maximum power transfer and maximum efficiency in a circuit ?****strong text**

Comment: please remove the bold formatting (what sense does making your whole question bold even make) and your strange leftover piece of text at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Maximum power is the highest voltage * current you can extract from the output

Maximum efficiency is when the loss of the circuit is the lowest ratio of the output power.

Generally the maximum efficiency of most converters will be somewhere around 50-70%, too low of an output power and all of the static losses, e.g. power consumption of chips in the circuit reduce it, and too high of an output power, and I<sup>2</sup>R losses mean you start losing a more significant share of the output power to heat through any resistances in the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The Maximum Power Transfer Theorem states that, to obtain maximum external power from a source with a finite internal resistance, the resistance of the load must be equal to the resistance of the source as viewed from its output terminals.

Application of the theorem is being limited to a DC circuit.

Considering 'V' as the source voltage, 'r' the source resistance, 'R' the load resistance and 'I' the load current:

Load current I = V/(r+R)

Power dissipated in the source = I²r

Power dissipated in the load = I²R

Total power dissipated = (I²r+I²R)

Efficiency= Power dissipated in the load/Total power dissipated =  I²R/(I²r+I²R) = R/(r+R)

Maximum power would be transferred from source to load when R=r. Under this condition efficiency = R/2R = 0.5.

Some sample values have been considered to make it easier to comprehend.

[image]

It is observed that under the condition of maximum power transfer the efficiency is at a maximum of 0.5.

Should maximum power transfer not be a condition, a higher efficiency is possible with a load resistance much higher than the source resistance.